# can you write 10th power in a formula in c# code?

Tags: c#, formula

I've been trying to get this formula to work. However, since adding the system for 10th powers, it doesn't work. I have tried writing them all out as Area1*math.pow(10,-Area1power) and also as Area1E-Area1power but the first doesn't come out with the correct answer and the second says area1e is not a name.
any advice on how to solve this?
this is my original code.

```
        {   //calculation of area reduction and drawing force
        Area1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtarea1.Text);
        Area2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtarea2.Text);
        Area1power = Convert.ToDouble(txtarea1power.Text);
        Area2power = Convert.ToDouble(txtarea2power.Text);
        areareduction = ((Area1 * Math.Pow(10, Area1power)) - (Area2 * Math.Pow(10, Area2power)) / (Area1 * Math.Pow(10, Area1power)));
        areareductionlimit = 0.63;
        txtareareduction.Text = areareduction.ToString();
        drawingforce = (Area2 * Math.Pow(10, Area2power)) * (Strengthcoeff / (WorkHardExp + 1)) * Math.Pow((Math.Log((Area1*Math.Pow(10, Area1power)) / (Area2 * Math.Pow(10, Area2power))), (WorkHardExp + 1)));
        txtdrawingforce.Text = drawingforce.ToString();
```

The formula for drawing force is

```
p=A2*(K/(N+1))*(LN(A1/A2))^(N+1)
A1=Area1
A2=Area2
K=strengthcoeff
N=WorkHardExp
```

Comment: Is the 'incorrect answer' close?  It could be you have rounding errors (in either your code or your expected).  I would also recommend you break down those long calculations into their components, and verify each step manually.  Have a separate line for : `var a1p = Area1*Math.Power(10, -Area1Power); var a2p = Area2*Math.Power(10, -Area2Power); ` etc

Comment: It looks like the second part of drawingForce formula has extra parenthesis. This does compile in my test solution `* Math.Pow(Math.Log((Area1 * Math.Pow(10, Area1power)) / (Area2 * Math.Pow(10, Area2power))), (WorkHardExp + 1));`

Comment: Thankyou that helped a lot, i've managed to get the area reduction correct but the drawing force is still quite far out however i think that is down to a rounding error somewhere.